# Better manner to enter dynamic fields?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

I've been designing an edit product field for my website, where users can have many prices for different "packages" of a certain product. I want the users to be able to order the packages in any order they want. So I list off the products, using a counter(that AIs on the prices table). If someone will tell me that how I'm doing this is stupid, and inform me of a much better design, I would appreciate it.

```
<?php
    $UserID = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_SESSION['userID']);
    $PID = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_SESSION['ePID']);
    $findpricesstmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE UserID = ? and PID= ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($findpricesstmt, 'ii', $UserID, $PID);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($findpricesstmt);
    $findpricesresult = mysqli_stmt_get_result($findpricesstmt);
    $findpricesrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($findpricesresult);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($findpricesresult) == 0) {
        echo('You currently have no prices for this product, meaning it is deactivated. To continue sales, add a price and click reactivate.');
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['count'] = 50;
        while($_SESSION['count'] > 0)
        {
            $count = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_SESSION['count']);
            $count1stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE Count = ? and UserID = ? and PID= ?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($count1stmt, 'iii', $count, $UserID, $PID);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($count1stmt);
            $count1result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($count1stmt);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($count1result) != 0) {
                include '../includes/orderpackmanu.php';
            }
            $_SESSION['count']--;
        }
    }
?>
```

In orderpackmanu.php, I have:

```
<?php
$count = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_SESSION['count']);

$displayprimanustmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT * FROM prices WHERE Count = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($displayprimanustmt, 'i', $count);
mysqli_stmt_execute($displayprimanustmt);
$displayprimanuresult = mysqli_stmt_get_result($displayprimanustmt);

if(mysqli_num_rows($displayprimanuresult) != 0) {
    $displayprimanurow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($displayprimanuresult);
    $price = $displayprimanurow['price'];
    $units = $displayprimanurow['units'];
    $ppu = $displayprimanurow['ppu'];
    $dispcode = $displayprimanurow['dispcode'];
}
?>
<div>
    <div style="width:55%;float:left;text-align:center;">
        <?php if(isset($price)){ echo $price . "$ for "; } if(isset($units)){ echo $units; } ?>
        <br>
        <?php if(isset($ppu)){ echo $ppu . "$ per unit"; } ?>
    </div>
    <div style="width:40%;float:left;">
        <input class="orderinput" type="text" name="<?php if(isset($count)){ echo $count; } ?>" placeholder="<?php if(isset($dispcode)){ echo $dispcode; } ?>" maxlength="30">
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <br>
</div>
```

My question is specifically about the input name (though any "total" solutions to this design are also acceptable). If I go with this format, and each input has it's own `dispcode` for a name, is there a simple way of going about the inputting process? Or somebody tell me why what I'm doing is fundamentally wrong, and how to fix it.

Comment: The first thing that caught my eye is do NOT combine `escape_string` with `bind_param`. The whole point of `bind_param` is to eliminate the need to escape string: data is treated as data, not part of query string.

Comment: @Passerby What reason is there not to use them both? Even if it is repetitive.

Comment: They are not "repetitive"; They are different things. Say you want to output `'WTF'`, in traditional escape style, you do `SELECT '(escape("'WTF'"))';` which end up with `SELECT '''WTF''';`; but in binding style, you do `SELECT ?; bind("'WTF'");`, to which DB parse as: `SELECT ?` where the **data** of `?` is `'WTF'`. If you combine those, DB will parse as `SELECT ?` where the data of `?` is `'''WTF'''`.

Comment: I can't see how that would ever cause an issue, but it is unnecessary. I've removed all escape strings.

Comment: Say you need to insert `That's good` to table. `INSERT INTO table VALUES (?); bind(escape("That's good"));` will _literally_ insert `That''s good`, while `INSERT INTO table VALUES (',escape("That's good"),')` AND `INSERT INTO table VALUES (?); bind("That's good");` will correctly insert `That's good`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wanted to identify an unknown number of fields as being unique, this was an interesting conundrum. I ended up using something similar to what is posted, except I added some identifying characters in beginning of the "name" field so that I could loop through them in my code:

```
$x = 1;
while(isset($_POST[$x])){
//input
$x++;
}
```

That doesn't work, because variable fields can't start with numbers. This does work:

```
$count;
$x = 'X'.$count;
while(isset($_POST[$x])){
//input
$count++;
$x = 'X'.$count;
}
```

Now there are still problems with it, but this was the largest/most confusing/easiest to explain thing I learned while doing this. I'm changing my code soon anyways, just going back and answering questions I asked with things I learned.